# How can I submit form from child to parent

Tags: angular

I want to  use one parentForm and when i click and save (and both fields) are empty it should show errors in both. Why it only shows in child component. Demo
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rnophs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Input property binding use FormGroupDirective. Injecting FormGroupDirective in child component will give the access to parentForm then we can add form Control dynamically.

**Try this:**

**child.component.ts**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormGroupDirective, NgForm, Validators, ControlContainer } from '@angular/forms';

/** @title Input with a custom ErrorStateMatcher */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-component',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css'],
  viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective }]
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private fgd: FormGroupDirective) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fgd.control.addControl('email', new FormControl())
  }
}
```

**parent.html**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="save()" class="example-form" [formGroup]="parentForm">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Email" formControlName="emailFormControl">
    <mat-error>
      Please enter a valid email address
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  <app-child-component></app-child-component>
  <button type="submit">save</button>
</form>
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7fnwkq

Comment: I modified little bit as i wanted save button in child component but ya that worked. Thanks

Comment: Now, Suppose If i get name from backend then I have to send it to the child in order to display in form. I want to do that from parent component. Any thoughts

Comment: you mean set the value to input field?

Answer (score -1):

You can use this form in save method:

```
if(this.parentForm.value.emailFormControl){

}
```